# How to set colors for bar plot with multiple layers in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to creat bar plot using three variables "stage", "sex" and "total" from data like below:

```
    residtraj             sex    stage          perc total
   <chr>                 <fct>  <fct>         <dbl> <int>
 1 born rural live rural female No cancer   0.00725     1
 2 born rural live rural female Early stage 0.02        1
 3 born rural live rural female Late stage  0.0462      3
 4 born rural live rural male   No cancer   0.00625     2
 5 born rural live rural male   Early stage 0.0323      4
 6 born rural live rural male   Late stage  0.0602     13
 7 born rural live urban female No cancer   0.138      19
 8 born rural live urban female Early stage 0.12        6
 9 born rural live urban female Late stage  0.215      14
10 born rural live urban male   No cancer   0.194      62
```

My code as:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(sex, total, fill=residtraj)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~stage) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(total,"(",percent(perc),")")),
            position=position_dodge(width=1), hjust=0.5, vjust=-1, size=2.5) +
  ylab("count(%)")+ ggtitle("Distribution of residence by sex and stage")
```

My question is, how can I set different color according to both "residtraj" and "sex"? (right now the color is automatically assigned only based on the value of "residtraj")

Comment: so you would have 4 colors? like 1 for rural + male , rural + female and so on..

Comment: Yes, like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `interaction` to join  "residtraj" and "sex" in the filling parameter of the `aes`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(sex, total, fill=interaction(residtraj,sex))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~stage)
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
structure(list(Row = 1:10, residtraj = c("bornruralliverural", 
"bornruralliverural", "bornruralliverural", "bornruralliverural", 
"bornruralliverural", "bornruralliverural", "bornruralliveurban", 
"bornruralliveurban", "bornruralliveurban", "bornruralliveurban"
), sex = c("female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
"female", "female", "female", "male"), stage = c("Nocancer", 
"Earlystage", "Latestage", "Nocancer", "Earlystage", "Latestage", 
"Nocancer", "Earlystage", "Latestage", "Nocancer"), perc = c(0.00725, 
0.02, 0.0462, 0.00625, 0.0323, 0.0602, 0.138, 0.12, 0.215, 0.194
), total = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 13L, 19L, 6L, 14L, 62L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55efd77ad350>)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need! In this case, may I ask one more question? Is it possible to mannually set the color of bars in this situation? Like using the scale_fill_manual?

Comment: Hey, you can see that the green bar takes up the whole block is one of the levels is zero. Any idea how that can be fixed? I was just thinking about that. Otherwise no problem since OP can live with it :)

Comment: @StupidWolf, you mean the bar for `bornruralliverural.male` ? I think it is because there is no value for the combination of Late Stage and bornruralliveurban.male

Comment: @user12721567, you're welcome ;). Yes you can use `scale_fill_manual(values = ...)` to fill the color you want to ;)

Comment: @StupidWolf Hi, because I just post part of my dataset. Like dc37 said, for the example data showed there, no observation in that category so it is zero.

Comment: No problem @user12721567 I understand you might not encounter this. This behavior is a bit unexpected due to the faceting, and I am asking whether there's a way to tackle this.

Comment: @StupidWolf, good question, I have the remember of an obscure option to set in order to keep spaces for empty columns... but I can't remember its name